# The longest string in the array(duplicating)

Tags: java, arrays, string

i've written program, that finds the longest string in the array. Now i need additional functionality. That includes just duplicating string in output, if number of maximum letters of n-string equals to m-string

For example input is:

1. this
2. should be
3. the longest
4. string
5. in an array

Output should be:

1. the longest
2. in an array

Since both of them(11 letters) are the longest strings (not only first of them, but both!). Thanks in advance!

Code below:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList <Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        String s = reader.readLine();
        list.add(i, s);
        numList.add(i, s.length());
    }

    int maxN = numList.get(0);
    String maxS = list.get(0);

    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {

        if(numList.get(i)>maxN) {
            maxN=numList.get(i);
            maxS = list.get(i);
        }  
    } 
    System.out.println(maxS);
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You have written the first part, so keep going

Comment: And i have no idea what to do futher ;(

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code generating service.  If you have a specific question, we will be much more likely to help you.

Comment: "Thanks in advance" (for the code that we're not going to write you)

Comment: Why not just continue with your existing code? loop again your list and filter out string length equals to your "maxN" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add another list which will contain your results and iterate over entries.

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    if(list.get(i).length()==maxS){
       result.add(list.get(i));
       System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to compare the string lengths of array elements with one another then strictly deal with those lengths encountered as you iterate through the initial **list** ArrayList. Not that you can't but there is no real need to create a yet another integer ArrayList to hold the element string lengths of everything contained within the original **list** ArrayList since you can establish that through your initial iteration. It's all a matter of what conditions you happen to set while the iteration is being carried out.

As @Efka has already pointed out, you can have yet another String ArrayList to hold the actual elemental strings which are of the longest (and of the same) length and then display those results.

It is naturally assumed that you have successfully filled the **list** ArrayList with string elements therefore:

```
ArrayList <String> dupList = new ArrayList<>(); // Will hold the results

// Need to start somewhere so...
// Initialize maxN with the string length of the first
// element contained within the 'list' ArrayList. 
int maxN = list.get(0).length(); 

// Add the first element to the duplicate list.
dupList.add(list.get(0));

// We start our iteration from 1 instead of 0
// because we've already processed index 0
// above to establish a starting point.
for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int length = list.get(i).length(); //get the element length
    if(length >= maxN) {
        if (length > maxN) { 
            // Clear the duplicate list since there is
            // now an elemental string that is longer.
            dupList.clear(); 
            // Set maxN to the new longest length
            maxN = list.get(i).length(); 
        }
        // Add the new longest or equal to the longest
        // element encountered to the duplicate list.
        dupList.add(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

To display the determined results you can use somethng like this:

```
// Display the determined results...
for (int i = 0; i < dupList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(dupList.get(i));
}
```